# Supercomputer Vs Human Brain

Tags: human-biology, brain

With supercomputers doing calculation in petaflops ($10^{15}$ Calculations per Second), have we crossed the speed of Human Brain?

Comment: Related question on Cognitive Sciences: [Why do scientists say brains are faster than computers?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/7855/4086)

Comment: Did you ask this question and then immediately answer it yourself... and then accept your own answer? This doesn't suit a biology forum either, it's information theory really.

Comment: @Louis: Will it be down voted if I say, yes? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a very big difference between doing the calculations needed to simulate the human brain (or any animal brain - we can do a fairly decent job on *C. elegans*), and doing computations.  While a basic leaky integrate & fire model is fairly simple, to *accurately* simulate a single neuron in real time takes a pretty fast computer.  See e.g. these links for more, http://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/,  http://bluebrain.epfl.ch/  http://www.artificialbrains.com/darpa-synapse-program.

Brains do well what computers do poorly, and vice versa.  The HP12C calculator on my desk, made in the early '80s, can do many sorts of mathematical calculations faster than I can, because brains aren't really optimized for doing, for example, compound interest calculations.  But my brain, or my dog's brain for that matter, can do all the 'calculations' needed to process a stream of images, recognize that they show a ball, predict its path, and catch it - while simultaneously processing visual, auditory, olfactory, and kinesthetic inputs for obstacle avoidance and threat recognition, and (in my case, anyway) perhaps thinking about how to solve complex programming problems.

Maybe I should add that there are basically three different things that a computer can do in this context:

1. Complex calculations, whether compound interest, weather modeling, seismic tomography or whatever.
2. Simulating the actual behavior of a brain, or some subset of one, starting from a single neuron.
3. Trying to replicate what a brain does through algorithms, or Artificial Intelligence.

(1) is what we mostly use computers for, and they're way better at it than human brains.  (2) is a special case of (1), which we do because we don't have much of an idea how to do (3), and having a simulated brain we can alter at will might help in learning how real brains do what they do.

Comment: In my opinion this is a much better answer than Devashish Das (OP)'s answer which got 15 up votes and is chosen as an answer at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I like this one too.

Comment: It is kind of meaningless to compare an analog device with a digital one to begin with.

Answer (score 22):

I will just show the statistics of last attempt to mimic the brain process.

In 2011 fastest computer in Japan was launched:

### **K computer OR SPARC64 VIIIfx 2.0GHz**

Features:

- **Manufacturer:**    Fujitsu
- **Cores:**   705,024
- **Linpack Performance (Rmax)**   10,510 TFlop/s
- **Theoretical Peak (Rpeak)** 11,280.4 TFlop/s
- **Power:**   12,659.89 kW
- **Memory:**  1,410,048 GB (16GB RAM per CPU)
- **Processor:**   SPARC64 VIIIfx 8C 2GHz (88,128 CPUs, 8-core each)
- **Operating System:**    Linux

It's currently world's **4th fastest supercomputer**.

Source: [Top 500 Supercoputers](http://www.top500.org/lists/2014/06/)

[image]

Image Source: http://wondergressive.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/WG-k-computer.jpg

Now,

> ### An 83,000-Processor Supercomputer Can Only Match 1% of Your Brain
>
> ...The most accurate simulation of the human brain to date has been
>   carried out in a Japanese supercomputer, with a single second’s worth
>   of activity from just one per cent of the complex organ taking one of
>   the world’s most powerful supercomputers 40 minutes to calculate.
>   Researchers used the K computer in Japan, currently the fourth most
>   powerful in the world, to simulate human brain activity. **The computer
>   has 705,024 processor cores and 1.4 million GB of RAM, but still took
>   40 minutes to crunch the data for just one second of brain activity**...
>
> Source: http://gizmodo.com/an-83-000-processor-supercomputer-only-matched-one-perc-1045026757

### Human Brain:

> ### Do we have brain to spare?
>
> by David A. Drachman, MD
>
> Within the liter and a half of human brain, stereologic studies
>   estimate that there are approximately **20 billion neocortical neurons,
>   with an average of 7,000 synaptic connections each**.1 The cerebral
>   cortex has **about 0.15 quadrillion synapses—or about a trillion
>   synapses per cubic centimeter of cortex**. The white matter of the brain
>   contains approximately **150,000 to 180,000 km of myelinated nerve
>   fibers at age 20**, connecting all these neuronal elements. Despite the
>   monumental number of components in the brain, Szentagothai estimated
>   that **each neuron is able to contact any other neuron with no more than
>   six interneuronal connections—“six degrees of separation.”**

[image]

Image Source: http://www.nature.com/polopoly_fs/7.2933.1329907514!/image/far-to-go.jpg_gen/derivatives/fullsize/far-to-go.jpg

### Why Brain beats Supercomputer?

> Why is it so hard for computers to reproduce what your grey matter
>   does as a matter of course? **Volume**. The human brain consists of about
>   200 billion nerve cells (neurons) that are linked together by
>   trillions of connections called synapses. As the tiny electrical
>   impulses shoot across each neuron, they have to travel through these
>   synapses, each of which contains about 1000 different switches that
>   route that electrical impulse. In total, one **human brain could contain
>   hundreds of trillions of these neural pathways**. It's like a Choose
>   Your Own Adventure book that stretches from here to Jupiter.

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: It is not just processing speed that affects the speed of calculation. Algorithms also play a great role. I am very sure that electrical circuits have a much much faster response than the ion-current based neuronal circuits. Speed of information flow is not the sole criteria.

Comment: @WYSIWYG: They have used open-source Neural Simulation Technology (NEST) = http://www.nest-initiative.org/

Comment: Fuzzy mathematics and neural networks can play vital role in up bringing  computer science to higher grounds of Artificial Intelligence. But only considering the computational and memory speed couldn't be a right criteria in the development. While we increase the computational power and memory of a computer finally it is the quality of the software that decides what we achieved.

Comment: I don't think that difficulty of simulation is good measure for such comparison.

Comment: What this simulation is doing is basically hardware emulation, which is always slow (try compared the speed of a video game on native hardware with an emulator, even on a faster computer).  By this logic, weather has much greater processing power than a supercomputer, because a supercomputer cannot accurately simulate weather.

Comment: Computers work very different from brains.  Douglas Hofstaedter wrote an excellent essay to explain this:  http://themindi.blogspot.dk/2007/02/chapter-11-prelude-ant-fugue.html

Answer (score 4):

A simple calculator (which is a computer) calculates 298465+46547 much faster than us. a PC forecast possible events faster than us. But even the fastest computer can't recognize a new pattern faster than us (the computer may never do that). So each one has its relative advantages.